# I need to call data from fireabse

Tags: java, android

I am not getting an error but I want to print the value that the user chooses inside the activity above and the image does successfully show up in the firebase storage but it just won't print in the image view. How do I resolve this. Here is my code

```html
package tech.ahawebsolutions.ahachatsandcalling;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button UpdateAccountSettings, logoutbutton;
    private EditText userName, userStatus;
    private ImageView userProfileImage, userProfileImage1;
    private String currentUserID;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference RootRef;
    private StorageReference userProfileImagesRef;
    private static final int GalleryPick = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        logoutbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logoutbutton);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        userProfileImagesRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile Images");


        userProfileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.set_profile_image);
        userProfileImage1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.set_profile_image1);
        
        InitializeFields();

        userName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        UpdateAccountSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                UpdateSettings();
            }
        });
        RetrieveUserInfo();

        logoutbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mAuth.signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));


            }
        });
        userProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GalleryPick);

            }
        });
    }



    private void UpdateSettings()
    {
        String setUserName = userName.getText().toString();
        String setUserStatus = userStatus.getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(setUserName))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(setUserStatus))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your status", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            HashMap<String, String> profileMap = new HashMap<>();
            profileMap.put("uid", currentUserID);
            profileMap.put("name", setUserName);
            profileMap.put("status", setUserStatus);

            RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).setValue(profileMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                {
                    if (task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Profile updated successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        SendUserToMainActivity();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String message = task.getException().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error :" + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }

    private void InitializeFields()
    {
        UpdateAccountSettings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_settings_button);
        userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.set_user_name);
        userStatus = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.set_profile_status);
        userProfileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.set_profile_image);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode==GalleryPick  &&  resultCode==RESULT_OK  &&  data!=null)
        {
            Uri ImageUri = data.getData();

            CropImage.activity()
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                    .start(this);
        }

        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {

                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();


                StorageReference filePath = userProfileImagesRef.child(currentUserID + ".jpg");

                filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task)
                    {
                        if (task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Profile Image uploaded Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            final String downloaedUrl = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                            RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("image")
                                    .setValue(downloaedUrl)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                                        {

                                            if (task.isSuccessful())
                                            {
                                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Image save in Database, Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                Picasso.get().load(downloaedUrl).into(userProfileImage);

                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                String message = task.getException().toString();
                                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            String message = task.getException().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }


    private void RetrieveUserInfo()
    {
        RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID)
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                    {
                        if ((dataSnapshot.exists()) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("name") && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("image"))))
                        {
                            String retrieveUserName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                            String retrievesStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
                            String retrieveProfileImage = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();

                            userName.setText(retrieveUserName);
                            userStatus.setText(retrievesStatus);

                            Picasso.get().load(retrieveProfileImage).into(userProfileImage);
                        }
                        else if ((dataSnapshot.exists()) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("name")))
                        {
                            String retrieveUserName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                            String retrievesStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();

                            userName.setText(retrieveUserName);
                            userStatus.setText(retrievesStatus);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            userName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Please set & update your profile information...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
    }


    private void SendUserToMainActivity() {
        Intent mainintent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        mainintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(mainintent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

The expected outcome would be the image the user selects and that is stored in firebase become called back and printed into the image view called userProfileImage. Thank you and if you can offer solutions that would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to pass the id of the view to method findViewById()... It shoud be something like findViewById(R.id.totalPoints)

Comment: @W0rmH0le could you clarify on that

Comment: Replace findViewById().setText by totalPoints.setText....

Answer (score 1):

findViewById(R.id.your_View_id) that was missing try to use view/data binding to avoid these problems

Comment: oh it says find view by id(int) in appcompatActivity cannot be applied to (java.lang.string)

Comment: problem here u need to specify wich view u need to find
 findViewById(-----).setText(document.getData().get("totalPoints").toString());
so what is the id of the textview u want data to be printed  in?@user13874345

Comment: findViewById(R.id.totalPoints).setText(document.getData().get("totalPoints").toString());
try this @user13874345